# Not getting proper json responses using python requests.get().json() on amazon ec2

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Something really weird is happening that I don't know if I can properly explain.
My python program sends a simple request and parses it as follows

```
    urlN = u'https://air.makemytrip.com/air/screen/ifsearch?tripType=O&' \
             'itinerary='+source+'-'+dest+'-D-
             '+str(date0)+'&paxType=A-1&' \
             'cabinClass='+cl

    page = requests.get(urlN, verify=False, timeout=15).json()
```

its inside a loop that increments the date by one, waits 5 sec, and so on.
Now the program works fine on my pc and laptop, but when I convert it to exe using pyinstaller, and run it on an amazon ec2 server, after 3 iterations, all the responses give the same error : json decode error

```
    json decode error expecting value line 1 column 1(char 0)
```

Am I missing something ? I did the same for domestic flights on make my trip (the request url changes), and it worked fine, but international flights are sometimes giving incomplete json responses, which i figured by printing page, while at other times I have no idea what's wrong.
Please help !!
(PS: I have also tried json.load to no avail)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a very similar situation. Everything works fine on my local computer but then when I push it up to EC2 I get the decode error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the data that you're getting is not a valid JSON.

It'll be also more pythonic if you had used format functions or %s placeholders:

```
url_template = (
    'https://air.makemytrip.com/air/screen/ifsearch?tripType=O&'
     'itinerary=%(source)s-%(dest)s-D-%(date0)s&paxType=A-1&'
     'cabinClass=%(c1)s'
)
page = requests.get(url_template % locals(), verify=False, timeout=15).json()
```

Comment: I am new to python, so thanks for the placeholders. But as I said, the json responses are being accepted just fine when I run the program from pycharm, or even the exe on my windows 10 laptop, but the when I run the same exe on Amazon ec2 remotely, it works for 2-3 iterations, then the json response goes haywire.

Comment: Then try to log response prior to transforming it to json. Then you'll exactly what was inside the response there.